# forbidden call to /tokens api

Tags: box-api

I'm trying the new "private beta" feature "Tokens" (http://developers.box.com/docs/#tokens) of box 2.0 using an API key, which I think has private beta access.

But I get the following response:

```
{
    "type":"error",
    "status":403,
    "code":"forbidden",
    "help_url":"http:\/\/developers.box.com\/docs\/#errors",
    "message":"Forbidden",
    "request_id":"10957639134febfbf1f1477"
}
```

Look like my obtained API key doesn't have access to the "Tokens" api. Is there any way to verify it? What do you guys think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Per the note in the documentation](http://developers.box.com/docs/#tokens), you'll need to contact us at apiATboxDOTcom in order to have this enabled.

Comment: I think my key has obtained access right from box. But I don't have way to verify it.

Comment: You can just email the address listed above, and we can confirm if it is or not.